# Какие CMS подойдут для сайта на котором все страницы имеют разную структуру?

Tags: веб-программирование, cms

Каждая страница сайта имеет разную структуру.

Comment: Зачем тогда CMS вообще нужна?

Comment: @andreymal чтобы заказчик мог самостоятельно менять содержимое на страницах